# CSS div height not stretching

Tags: php, html, css

I'm programming a website and on a page I have dynamic content. To be specific I want to display some content in a div each. And the main div wont stretch upon this content.

```
#main{
    position:relative;
    background-image:url(images/main_middle.png);
    background-repeat:repeat-y; 
    width:850px;
    min-height:450px;
}
.intrebari{
    position:relative;
    width:400px;
    min-height:150px;
    padding:20px;
}

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($rezultat)){
    echo '<div class="intrebari">
                 <div id="upleft"></div>
         <div id="upright"></div>
         <div id="downleft"></div>
         <div id="downright"></div>
        '.$_SESSION['username'].' a intrebat:<br />
        '.$row['question'].'
         </div>';
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to understand the problem you are facing. Is it a CSS problem? Perhaps showing your HTML structure would help.

Comment: I think is a css problem. I showed you the html/php of the .intrebari div. That div is in another div that is floated right. The right floated div is in the main div. It looks that the right floated div streches after its content, but the main div wouldn't so the content is reaching out of the page:|

Comment: I had this issue with some flexbox content inside a div. Fixed it using `height: auto;` on the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal div has to be cleared so the outer should know the height of the inner div
you may use a class

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

and introduce it after your inner div inside outer div main

```
echo '<div class="intrebari">
                 <div id="upleft"></div>
         <div id="upright"></div>
         <div id="downleft"></div>
         <div id="downright"></div>
        '.$_SESSION['username'].' a intrebat:<br />
        '.$row['question'].'
         </div><div class="clear"></div>';
```

this will help you

If you have given float to intrebari, you need to give float left or right to main div to get the main wrap the inner content

Answer (score 0):

```
.intrebari{
    position:relative;
    width:100%
    min-height:150px;
    padding:20px;
}
```

if you want to have the content of the div.intrebari stretch horizontaly  make the width of value to 100%

Comment: I said that the main div wouldn't stretch verticaly if the while cycle generates more content.